# xhr (ajax) request NOT sending all cookies (nodeJS)

Tags: node.js, http-headers, session-cookies, setcookie

With nodeJS i am successfully setting a cookie.

[image]

When i call a page, I am making 2 requests.

One for the initial page and an ajax request once the DOM has loaded

http://domain.com/pages/blog

http://domain.com/dataRequest

My cookie appears in the initial request on the node server

http://domain.com/pages/blog

```
b_switch_session_id=3442047e6f50effc9108709bae089aa4;  
_shopify_y=F8DD2A56-4D75-4478-ACF4; 
_shopify_y=F8DD2A56-4D75-4478-ACF4;
ajs_anonymous_id=%2258922eb3-abd1-44a6-a35b-4dbe00bf62ba%22; 
_session_id=40ac642b90ec66f0da1b0f6af9176f7d;  
_shopify_visit=t; 
_shopify_uniq=x; 
_shopify_s=8B5A83C5-3B48-4EF7-816A;
_shopify_s=8B5A83C5-3B48-4EF7-816A;
ajs_group_id=null; 
ajs_user_id=null;
_ga=GA1.2.1751239978.1452678921; 
_gat=1
```

But not in the ajax request

```
    ajs_anonymous_id=%2258922eb3-abd1-44a6-a35b-4dbe00bf62ba%22; 
    _session_id=40ac642b90ec66f0da1b0f6af9176f7d; 
    _shopify_y=F8DD2A56-4D75-4478-ACF4; 
    _ga=GA1.2.1751239978.1452678921; 
    _gat=1; 
    _shopify_visit=t; 
    _shopify_uniq=x; 
    _shopify_s=8B5A83C5-3B48-4EF7-816A; 
    ajs_group_id=null; 
    ajs_user_id=null
```

Note: For some reason shopify sets duplicate cookies. These duplicate cookies appear in request.headers on node for the initial request, but the duplicates do note appear in node for the ajax request

```
function callAjax(Url) 
    {  
       //get domain name from url
        var url = Url
        var arr = url.split("/");
        var domain = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2]
        var ref = window.location.href;
         //console.log(ref);

        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {

        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", domain+"/dataRequest", true);
        xmlhttp.send(ref);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The cookie was setting its self for the path of the specific page /blog

fix:

```
{'set-cookie':'b_switch_session_id=lsd34JF3krK; path=/'}
```